# Use .replace() method to replace multiple words in a string/input using Python

Tags: python

Okay, so I am having severe issues trying to figure out how I can possibly do this. I know it can be incredibly simple using a `.split` of the `userInput` then a module involving a for statement and `.replace`.

Say I want to use a list of words I wish to replace like

```
dict1 = ( "zero", "nil", "null" )
```

user inputs after being split

```
userInput = "I", "want", "zero", "to", "do", "with", "you"
```

I want to use the `.replace()` within a module and for loop to replace the word zero with another word like "one".

Any help is appreciated. For loops are quite confusing to me and so is `.replace` as I don't think you can use something like `splitInput.replace ( dict1, "one" )`.

Comment: `replace` replaces substrings of a string, not elements of a list; if you want to replace elements of a list, something like a dict lookup makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why split the input at all?

```
replace_dict = { 'zero': 'one', 'nil': 'two', 'null': 'three'}
userInput = "I want zero, zilch, zip, nil to do with you"

modified = userInput

for k in replace_dict.keys():
    modified = modified.replace(k, replace_dict[k])

print(modified)
```

Execution output:

```
$ python3 repl.py 
$ I want one, zilch, zip, two to do with you
```

Comment: Interesting, I think I can work with this to do what I want. Appreciate your help! And so simple, holy smokes thank you

Comment: "Why split the input at all?" - well, for one thing, it'd help avoid replacing the "nil" in "I love vanilla ice cream".

Comment: Well, I do want it to replace words inside of words. I didn't state that, but I do want it to work like that. So if a word like before popped up. I want it to change to befifth.